# Question about estimating taylor remainder

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Let $u: U \in \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, with $u \in C^{1, \alpha}(U)$.

So $$\sup_{x \neq y} \frac{|u(x) - u(y)|}{|x-y|^\alpha} < \infty,$$
and $$\sup_{x \neq y} \frac{|u'(x) - u'(y)|}{|x-y|^\alpha} < \infty.$$

Let $p(x)$ be the taylor polynomial of $u$ centered at $0$. Let $R(x)$ represent the taylor remainder term, so that $u(x) = p(x) + R(x)$.

I saw the following estimate in some notes, but I dont see how we get it.

Let $\delta>0$.

$$ \sup_{B_\delta(0)} |R(x)| \leq \delta \sup_{B_\delta(0)} |u'(x) - u'(0)| $$

I think I am missing something simple. Note: I don't know if we need the fact that $u$ is holder continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since subtracting a first-order polynomial doesn't change anything here we can assume wlog $$u(0)=u'(0)=0.$$

The version of Taylor's Theorem that seems to be the best known says that $$R(x)=xu'(\xi),\quad(\xi\in(0,x)).$$hence $$\sup_{|x|\le\delta}|R(x)|\le\delta\sup_{|x|\le\delta}|u'(x)|.$$